# Perl -- suppress console output?

Tags: perl, console

I'd like a native way to fix this problem...

I have a perl command that makes a call that, sometimes, prints out text directly to the console.

I want something like this:

```
$text = get_output_from(MagicCommandICan'tChange());
if ($text neq "a specific value") {
  print $text;
}
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: Consider rephrasing the question. From your problem description, I take it you don't really want to suppress console output, you want to capture it.

Comment: You really should say what kind of command `MagicCommandICan'tChange()` is. Perl? System?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [`IO::CaptureOutput`](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aCaptureOutput)

```
 use IO::CaptureOutput qw(capture qxx qxy);

 # STDOUT and STDERR separately
 capture { noisy_sub(@args) } \$stdout, \$stderr;
```

Comment: Perfection. Oh perl, you are so powerful and evil.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this Perl script is calling an external executable. If the output is being printed on stdout, you can use the backtick operators or `qx` to run the command and capture the output. On a Unix system, you could use `system()` and redirect the output to `/dev/null` with the `>` operator. You can also call [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) with the command:

> If the filename begins with '|', the filename is interpreted as
>      a command to which output is to be piped, and if the filename
>      ends with a '|', the filename is interpreted as a command that
>      pipes output to us.  See "Using open() for IPC" in perlipc for
>      more examples of this.  (You are not allowed to "open" to a
>      command that pipes both in and out, but see IPC::Open2,
>      IPC::Open3, and "Bidirectional Communication with Another
>      Process" in perlipc for alternatives.)

Finally, you could close and reopen the STDOUT and STDERR filehandles (*edit*: `IO::CaptureOutput` was recommended below). This is kind of weird, though; I wouldn't recommend it as the best alternative.